# Project with a python loop program

Tags: python

My son has this project he has to do in python and is stuck.

He needs to make a number guessing game. The code must generate a random secret number between 0 and 10, then give the user 5 attempts to guess that number, each guess if not correct must indicate if it is higher or lower than the secret random number. After each guess the code needs to display text stating what has happened. The code also needs to store all guesses and display them at the end. Needs to be made using loop, if, elif, else and an array or list code.

The attempt so far is below

```
print("Hi there, lets play a little guessing game. Guess the number between 0 and 10")
from random import randint
x = [randint(0,10)]
counter = 0

guess = input("Enter guess:")

while counter < 5:
    print("You have " + str(counter) + " guesses left")
    counter = counter +1

    if guess == x:
        print("Congrats you got it")
        break
    elif guess > x:
        print("Too high")
    elif guess < x:
        print("Too low")
    else:
        print("You lost")
        break
```

Any help to correct my sons code would be appreciated as this project is due soon and he cannot access his tutor

Comment: What's the problem now? Basic [list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) should satisfy your requirement. Please give a minute to read the doc. Also I believe this should have been covered in school.

Comment: You need to ask for the input __within__ the loop. Otherwise, the user is only asked once for their guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. What the code does is explained in comments below.
You need to do `x=randint(0,10)` which will assign the random number to a variable, i.e `x=4` rather than `x = [randint(0,10)]`, which assigns the random number to a list ,`x=[4]```

Also you need to ask for a guess in the loop, instead of doing it only one before the loop started.
Also you would need to convert the string to an int for comparison i.e. `guess = int(input("Enter guess:"))`

```
print("Hi there, lets play a little guessing game. Guess the number between 0 and 10")
#Create a random number
from random import randint
x = randint(0, 10)
counter = 0
won = False

#Run 5 attempts in a loop
while counter<5:
    #Get the guess from the user
    guess = int(input("Enter guess:"))

    counter = counter+1
    #Check if the guess is the same, low or high as the random number
    if guess == x:
        print("Congrats you got it")
        won = True
        break
    elif guess > x:
        print("Too high")
    elif guess < x:
        print("Too low")
    print("You have " + str(5 - counter) + " guesses left")

#If you didn't won, you lost
if not won:
    print("The number was ", x)
    print("You Lost")
```

Comment: You are unstoppable, it worked very well and his quite impressed, thanks.

I dont want to take up anymore of your time, but would you be able to recommend a good guide for python at this level?

Comment: Yes let me look something up. Meanwhile if the answer helped you, please upvote/accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So here are the corrections. So x has been initialized as array rather than an integer. So none of the comparisons with guess will be working. Also the counter logic is wrong. Rather than starting from zero, start from 5 which is the maximum number of chances and go from the reverse rather. Then at each if/elif loop append all the guesses and print it in the end.

Here is the corrected code

```
from random import randint
x = randint(0,10)
print(x)
counter = 5
guesses=[] #initalize an empty list to store all guesses

while counter != 0:
    guess = input("Enter guess:")

    if guess == x:
        print("Congrats you got it")
        guesses.append(guess)
        break
    elif guess > x:
        print("Too high")
        guesses.append(guess)
    elif guess < x:
        print("Too low")
        guesses.append(guess)
    else:
        print("You lost")
        break

    counter = counter-1
    print("You have " + str(counter) + " guesses left")

print(guesses)
```

Comment: This code will work in Python 2. If this is Python 3, `input()` returns a string, which must be converted to an `int` for the comparison with `x` to work.

Comment: This does work in python 2. I just wanted to point out the logic without being too specific on other things.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: 
`x = [randint(0,10)]` wouldn't work as you are creating a list here instead of single guess
`print("You have " + str(counter) + " guesses left")` is also incorrect. You might instead set counter to 5 and check for counter > 0 and do counter -= 1, that way message can be fixed
Lastly to store all guesses you would need a variable

```
from random import randint

if __name__ == "__main__":
    number_to_guess = randint(0,10)
    guesses = []
    for c in range(5,0,-1):
        guessed = input("Enter guess:")
        guessed = guessed.strip()
        assert guessed.isnumeric()
        guessed = int(guessed)
        guesses.append(guessed) 
        if guessed == number_to_guess:
            print("yes")
            break
        elif guessed > number_to_guess:
            print("more")
        else:
            print("less")            
        c -= 1
        print("pending guesses", c)
    print("Expected - ", number_to_guess)
    print("All guesses - ", guesses)
```

Comment: Actually I think you shouldn't give the answer directly.

Comment: this is for the kid :-)

Comment: Thanks ranjith, ill have to run it past him, the code even boggles me

Comment: Code-only answers are highly discouraged. One reason being that they promote [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). You should explain what's wrong with the code in the question, and how it can be solved. And preferably only show enough code to illustrate the solution, but not something that can be copy-pasted as a whole. Please take some time to [read about how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).